# Bash pathname expansion and usage with git?

Tags: git, bash

I've been bashing my head on my keyboard over this one for too long now, and it is difficult to search for without getting lots of similar but ultimately unhelpful questions.

I've got a set of git repositories on a shared drive that I manage with some bash scripts.  For now, I am forced to use a dual boot setup for some software that I can't make work well under wine, so my problem is in windows 7 specifically with git bash.

I have some code like this:

```
win_shared="//path/to/shared/drive/RepoParentDir/"
nix_shared="/mnt/shared/RepoParentDir/"

// ... other stuff ...

# $dir is the current repo working directory (in a loop),
# and $working is the local path above RepoParentDir (fixed for lifetime of the script)
repo_dir=${dir#$working/}

nix=$(printf '%q' "$nix_shared$repo_dir.git")
echo "\$nix = $nix"
git remote add nix_origin "$nix"

win=$(printf '%q' "$win_shared$repo_dir.git")
echo "\$win = $win"
git remote add win_origin "$win"

git remote -v

// ...
```

but, this is the output that I'm getting (with the redundant git pull paths omitted):

```
$nix = /mnt/shared/RepoParentDir/clients/Client\ Repo\ Name.git
$win = //path/to/shared/drive/clients/Client\ Repo\ Name.git

nix_origin  C:/Program Files/Git/mnt/shared/RepoParentDir/clients/Client/ Repo/ Name.git (fetch)
win_origin  //path/to/shared/drive/RepoParentDir/clients/Client/ Repo/ Name.git (fetch)
```

Notice how the escaping is correct when echoed, but as soon as it goes to the git add remote command, the escaping is done with the wrong slash, and the path to git bash is prepended to my linux path variable.

I've tried all kinds of things from similar questions about bash pathname expansion, which is how I landed on the printf solution to escaping the strings, but I was having a similar problem when I would just output "$nix" and "$win" directly and either git would choke or end up with an incorrect remote path.

I'm not sure what's going on here at all, as I'm a bash and unix noob still.

EDIT:

I also just noticed in my log file that this ONLY happens when the path name ONLY has spaces that need to be escaped and no other special characters.  BUT, if there are any other special character in the pathname, like an apostrophe (which a few of my repos have), then all of the escaping is done correctly and comes out exactly as I expect in BOTH the echo and git commands, also it does NOT add the `C:/Program Files/Git/` to the path in this case either. This is the case regardless if there are spaces also in the same pathname.  So, with:

```
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/Client's Repo Name.git
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/Client'sRepoName.git
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/[ClientRepoName].git
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/[Client Repo Name].git
```

I get

```
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/Client\'s\ Repo\ Name.git
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/Client\'sRepoName.git
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/\[ClientRepoName\].git
/mnt/shared/RepoParent/\[Client\ Repo\ Name\].git
```

as I would expect.

Sorry if this is hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

[Edited to add item 2]

1. Don't do that `printf`.   Just:

   ```
   git remote add "${win_shared}${repo_dir}.git"
   ```

   assuming `$repo_dir` expands to something with a leading path-name separator, or `$win_shared` expands to something with a trailing path-name separator (either suffices and the latter is the case in your example).  The braces around the variable names are for clarity, not correctness, in this particular case.
2. (A) The `.git` directory itself is used both under Windows and Linux ("on a shared drive"), and (B) you're adding a remote using a full path ("//network/..." on Windows, "/mnt/shared/..." on Linux).  But Windows and Linux have very different ideas about what a "full path" looks like.  The path "/mnt/shared/..." on Windows is *not* a full path, so Windows tries to qualify it: "C:/.../mnt/shared/...".  On the other hand, he path "//network/..." is a full path on Linux but the leading "/" is redundant and might well get removed there.

   As a result, you may not be able to use `git remote add` for a path that is invalid on the system on which you are currently running.  The easiest way to handle that is to add the Windows remote while using Windows, and the Linux remote while using Linux.  An alternative is to use a lower level mechanism, by noting that:

   ```
   git remote add <name> <path>
   ```

   works, under the covers, by doing:

   ```
   git config "remote.<name>.url" "<path>"
   git config "remote.<name>.fetch" "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<name>/*"
   ```

   The difference between doing this with the low level `git config` command and doing it with `git remote add` is that `git remote add` understands the *meaning* of each and forcibly encodes the correct (for that OS) `<path>` part.  (Well, that, plus `git remote add` presumably knows to do something clever if the configuration section already exists, rather than merely overwriting it.)

#### Discussion

You are hitting a bunch of related and [deeply intertwingled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertwingularity) problems that can be summed up by great philosophical question of [epistemology](http://www.iep.utm.edu/epistemo/).  In this case, though, we can toss a lot of it aside and say:

1. How do you know what Git thinks the path-string is?
2. How do you *tell* Git what path-string to *use*?  In particular, if you know what to use, how do you convince *bash* to *tell Git?*

The nice thing about using `git remote -v` is that it prints things without [*encoding*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/encoding).<sup>1</sup>  So, when you see:

```
win_origin  //path/to/shared/drive/RepoParentDir/clients/Client/ Repo/ Name.git
```

you can be reasonably sure that this is what Git thinks it should be using, slashes and spaces and all.  (If your screen uses a fixed-width font you can even tell *how many* spaces there are, although how will you know if there are some *trailing* spaces?)

Bash, however, has options to do encoding in both *input* and *output* directions.  There are numerous reasons for that, but one is glaringly obvious: if you enter a command like:

```
echo hello world
```

bash needs to know to run the program `echo`, passing two arguments `hello` and `world`, rather than running the program `echo hello`, passing one argument `world`, or perhaps run the program `echo hello world`, passing no arguments at all.

Hence, bash often—*but not always*—believes that a space separates what we might as well call words.  That's great and all, but *what if we need to run the `echo hello` program?*  Well, then, we can *input*-encode it with a backslash:

```
echo\ hello world
```

Now bash knows to treat `echo hello` as a single atomic unit (a word), then break at the space, then treat `world` as a second atomic unit.

Unlike Windows, Unix/Linux have the shell (bash, or some other shell like sh or zsh or dash or tcsh—they're mostly named `*sh`) expand file name arguments too.  So if you type in:

```
echo *
```

it's the *shell* that finds all your files, and replaces `*` with those file names.  Each file name becomes its own "word", *even if the file name contains a space.*  The key here is that space-decode happens *before* `*`-decode.  Well, sort of: for instance, bash's input encoding includes the rule "backslash before something: eat the backslash while disabling the usual interpretation of the something."  This rule is applied once, but:

```
echo \*
```

simply prints out `*`, because the backslash disabled the special interpretation of `*`.  So we see that the *timing* of backslash protection depends on the timing of the special interpretation, too.

There are other ways to protect characters from the shell, and you are using them in:

```
"$win_shared$repo_dir.git"
```

but not in:

```
repo_dir=${dir#$working/}
```

Double quotes, in particular, protect spaces from being word-breakers, and protect asterisks and single quotes from their actions, but *do not* protect against dollar-sign variable name expansion.

(Single quotes, by contract, protect everything except single quotes.  So `'$dir'` avoids expanding `$dir`.)

When you use `%q` in a bash `printf` directive, you are telling bash to use *output-side* encoding.  That is, if that particular one of printf's atomic-unit ("word") arguments contains some special characters that, if typed in, bash would *now* interpret, quote them—bash uses prefix backslash since that is the simplest method.  Hence space turns into backslash-space.

But if you have something in a shell variable, it's already possible to make it a single atomic word: just put double quotes around it:

```
bash$ x='*'
bash$ echo "$x"
*
```

Without the double quotes, the shell would first expand `$x` to `*`, then expand `*` to all the files.  With the double quotes, we both protect any spaces, and prevent `*`-expansion.  The only thing we don't protect against is literal double quotes, but the double-quote handling happens at the *input* step, before the `$x` *expansion* step, so that's actually OK:

```
bash$ x='"'
bash$ echo "$x"
"
```

A big part of computer programming lies in dealing correctly with input and output encoding / expansion.  If you get it wrong, well, remember [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

---

<sup>1</sup>Except, of course, that every time we use a computer, we're encoding and decoding.  Is "wheat" the same thing as "Пшеница"?  The latter is Cyrillic-encoded Russian word, ASCII-spelling "pshenitsa", meaning "wheat".  Look at all the layers of encoding! :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I love it.  However, after trying your suggestion, it has solved only part of my problem.  Yes, Git is no longer choking on the paths and they seem to be getting set properly, but I still get "C:/Program Files/Git/" prepended to any path that does not have a special character within it, specifically on the linux "/mnt/shared/..."  paths, which don't actually exist in Git bash on windows.  What is going on there and how do I stop it?

Comment: I did not look closely at those, but ... if you can't access /mnt/shared in the first place, why `git add` it? I suspect the problem in this case is that Windows Git requires a leading drive letter for non-URL-ish, non-//-ish paths.

Comment: my whole reason is to set up two remotes for my dual boot to pull from, one that works under windows, and the other under ubuntu.

Comment: Hm, so, this is on a file system that gets mounted regardless of which OS you boot? Ah, right, it's right there at the top, "shared drive" :-) You can probably get the right effect if you create the remote itself only under the correct OS, or perhaps sidestep `git remote add` entirely by using `git config` (which can do everything `git remote` adds but has no "smarts" in it, which will be what you want since being "smart" results in adding drive letters!).

Comment: I might do the only create the remote under the correct OS, but it would be much easier to do it at the repo creation time for me.  Basically, I have a script for setting up a new git repo (new client) on the shared drive and cloning it locally, and another to run an automated (cron) push/pull over all the repos to keep them in sync in case I forget to do so manually (not often), but it makes it nice to have the remotes set up in the create script rather than have to check for failure later and set up at that point.

Comment: I just added a description of how to use `git config` to implement `git remote add` "by hand".

Comment: ok, something weird is still going on, I've simplified this whole problem by mounting the shared drive under git bash so it would appear in the exact same location, ```/mnt/shared``` regardless of OS and I could have a single ```origin``` again.  However, when the code ```git add origin "$repo"``` runs pathnames with special characters are processed fine and added to origin as ```/mnt/shared/expected/path/to/repo.git```, but those without special characters (with or without spaces) are still added as ```//unc-path/to/shared/drive/path/to/repo.git```, what do you think is going on here?

Comment: I avoid Windows whenever I possibly can (which is most of the time), so I'm not at all sure what Windows is doing here. Certainly Git under Linux should behave well, though, so if you can create these always with Linux, it should work properly.

Comment: me too, but I do graphic design and printing so I need photoshop and illustrator, and there are no suitable replacements under linux (gimp is close, but Inkscape does not import many of my thousands of Illustrator files properly and lacks CMYK colorspace support), and both adobe products are terribly slow under wine.

Comment: I've posted a clarified question here as I believe my original question had 2 problems due to my failure to double quote the path names, but this seems more of a cygwin/msys/git bash on windows issue AFAIK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939075/wrong-path-with-git-bash-for-windows-when-using-remote-add

Comment: Heh, I get around that by using Photoshop on a Mac. (Not that I use it professionally.)