# Wrong path with Git Bash for Windows when using remote add?

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, msys

I have some bash code like this:

```
repo="/mnt/shared/my/repo path sometimes with spaces.git"
echo "\$repo = $repo"
git remote add origin "${repo}"
git remote -v
```

where `/mnt/shared` is a mountpoint to a network drive created in the git cygwin fstab file that works fine.  I can interact with it through the Git bash shell using ls and pushing and pulling repos from it no problem.

I use the above code in a loop to maintain a large set of repos, and if my `repo` variable is like above without any special characters at all (aside from spaces, which don't affect this situation at all), I get the following output:

```
$repo = /mnt/shared/my/repo path sometimes with spaces.git
origin //unc-path/to/mountpoint/my/repo path sometimes with spaces.git (fetch)
origin //unc-path/to/mountpoint/my/repo path sometimes with spaces.git (pull)
```

or

```
$repo = /mnt/shared/my/repopathnospaces.git
origin //unc-path/to/mountpoint/my/repopathnospaces.git (fetch)
origin //unc-path/to/mountpoint/my/repopathnospaces.git (pull)
```

BUT, if the `repo` variable contains any special character that would normally require escaping (again, except for spaces for some reason), then I get the output that I am actually looking for (which I want in the above case too):

```
$repo = /mnt/shared/my/repo path with [brackets].git
origin /mnt/shared/my/repo path with [brackets].git (fetch)
origin /mnt/shared/my/repo path with [brackets].git (pull)
```

or

```
$repo = /mnt/shared/my/repopathwith[brackets].git
origin /mnt/shared/my/repopathwith[brackets].git (fetch)
origin /mnt/shared/my/repopathwith[brackets].git (pull)
```

Notice how it kept my `/mnt/shared` mountpoint in the path?  My question is, why in the heck is it converting to the UNC path in the first case (no special characters)?  And how can I get it to always maintain the mountpoint relative path here?

I'm using what I believe is the most recent version of Git Bash for Windows, and running `uname` gives me `MINGW64_NT-6.1` if that helps at all.

Comment: You can simplify that third line to `git remote add origin "$repo"`, since you aren't capturing the output to anything. I don't expect that to fix anything, but best to simplify things where possible.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I had try to encapsulate it there in my attempts to fix my overall problem, but I will change it back in my script now since it didn't make any difference.